# Key down event of text box in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I have to use key down event on text box. Code for the event looks like this:

```
 Private Sub TextBox1_Keydown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As
 System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles textBox1.KeyDown   
 If e.KeyCode = keys.Enter Then
    MessageBox.Show("Hello")   
 End If
 End Sub
```

But it gives the following error:

```
Handles clause requires a WithEvents variable defined in the containing type  
or one of its base types. (BC30506)
```

what does it mean? what i have to do for this?

Please help me out.

Thanks for your kind help.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the textbox is defined with `WithEvents` keyword.
Example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6k46st1y%28VS.71%29.aspx).

EDIT: For your case, the definition should look like
`WithEvents TextBox1 as TextBox`

Comment: I have declared like this :

private withevents textBox1 as textbox
I am getting the following error:

'textBox1' is already declared as 'Private WithEvents textBox1 As System.Windows.Forms.TextBox' in this class. (BC30260) 

Thanks for ur kind reply. what is the problem?

Comment: In that case, you have multiple definitions. One of it could be in designer generated code (`'Private WithEvents textBox1 As System.Windows.Forms.TextBox`) which you are shadowing by re-declaring it again & hence this error. Remove the 2nd definition, which you've added completely.

Comment: when i remove this definition from the code, the above stated error comes i.e. Handles clause requires a WithEvents variable defined in the containing type  or one of its base types. (BC30506).
I am not able to figure it out where to define and what to define.
Thanks a lot. help me.

Comment: Make sure you have only one definition `Private WithEvents textBox1 As System.Windows.Forms.TextBox` in the .cs & its .designer.cs file.

Answer (score 0):

On your {formname}.Designer.vb file check if you have something like this declared on it:

```
Friend WithEvents TextBox1 As System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
```

Comment: I have done this but the following error comes

'TextBox1' is already declared as 'Private textBox1 As System.Windows.Forms.TextBox' in this class. (BC30260)

Help me. Thanks a lot.